# computer won't shutdown because of power management

Tags: shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and when I run "sudo shutdown 0", the computer doesn't  shutdown. It gets stuck on "Disabling Power Management".

Any idea of what's happening?

Thanks in advance.

Also, this seems to happen more when using battery instead of AC.

Comment: Does running shutdown like:

 `sudo shutdown -P now`

make any difference?

Comment: What does -P change? I can't try it right now, but I will later.

Comment: Using -P worked. But is there a way I don't have to use it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you running a command-line only system, or do you have a GUI? If you have a command-line only system and you thus must shut down from the command-line, can you explain why `sudo shutdown -P now` is insufficient for your needs? If you have a GUI, then are you able to shut down by clicking the power/configuration icon at the upper-right corner of the screen and clicking Shut Down?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

man shutdown:

```
   -P     Requests that the system  be  powered  off  after  it  has  been
          brought down.
    ...

   -h     Requests  that  the system be either halted or powered off after
          it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to
          the system.
```

Seeing that -P works for you. Now it's a question of *why not*? The usual cmd to shutdown is `shutdown -h now`. In old school init based systems there was a config file that tweaks shutdown when entered from this point. From my initial investigation it turns out upstart falls back to init.d scripts to handle this. With global configuration living in `/etc/default/halt` and the actual script is `/etc/init.d/halt`.

It looks like "POWEROFF" is the default action, so  if you just did `halt` or `shutdown -h` or `telinit 0`, it should also power off.

`[/etc/init.d/halt]`

```
    # If INIT_HALT=HALT don't poweroff.
    poweroff="-p"
    if [ "$INIT_HALT" = "HALT" ]
    then
            poweroff=""
    fi
```

Since `INIT_HALT=POWEROFF` (defined in /etc/default/halt), that `poweroff='-p'` stays set. To debug this it should be as simple as adding the vars populated at the end of the script like so.

```
 log_action_msg "Will now halt:  $netdown $poweroff $hddown"
```

I wonder if your shutdown cmds are simply overriding the init configuration? In which case `telinit 0`should also shutdown the server and should become the first choice in performing this action.

Comment: If -P doesn't address your issue then you might have an ACPI/BIOS bug worthy of a bug report.